# animationDidStop not executing

Tags: swift, caanimation

I was working on trying to get a background view for a project I'm making and came across a weird instance.

This is how my code is set up.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController, CAAnimationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var startLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdButton: UIButton!

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientSet = [[CGColor]]()
var currentGradient: Int = 0

let gradientOne = gradientColors.lightGrey.cgColor
let gradientTwo = gradientColors.darkGrey.cgColor
let gradientThree = gradientColors.veryDarkGrey.cgColor

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    gradientSet.append([gradientOne, gradientTwo])
    gradientSet.append([gradientTwo, gradientThree])
    gradientSet.append([gradientThree, gradientOne])


    gradient.frame = colorView.bounds
    gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
    gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true
    colorView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, below: thirdButton.layer)

    animateGradient()

}

func animateGradient() {

    if currentGradient < gradientSet.count - 1 {
        currentGradient += 1
    } else {
        currentGradient = 0
    }

    let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 5.0
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradientChangeAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    gradientChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradient.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
}



func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if flag == true {
        print("animation complete")
        gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
        animateGradient()
    }
}

}
```

The problem I'm having is that when the animation is finished, the 'animationDidStop' never triggers. The first animation runs, but when it's finished it's supposed to run the 'animationDidStop' function and run the 'animateGradient' function on a constant loop. I've looked and looked for solutions online but can't seem to find one. Im running Swift 4 and would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Why would `animationDidStop` ever run? Of course it doesn't run. You are not configuring things so that it does run. You need to make this the completion function for the animation if you want it to run when the animation completes.

Comment: How would you recommend going about that? @matt

Comment: Set the `delegate` property of your animation objects to `self`

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out a line:

```
gradientChangeAnimation.delegate = self
```